# Hibernate Oracle Tablespace Annotation

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, annotations

I'm annotating my DAOs and using hibernate3:hbm2ddl to generate the ddls.  Is there a way to annotate the tablespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it out of the box. I've got around it in the past using the following - rather involved - approach:

1. Create your own annotation, `@TableSpec` that has tablespace and other necessary attributes.
2. Extend `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` and override `getTableMappings()` to return decorated `Table` objects (see below).
3. Extend `org.hibernate.mapping.Table` and override `sqlCreateString()` and / or `sqlAlterStrings()` to append tablespace specification (and additional settings if any).
4. Instead of using hbm2ddl tool (or ant task) write your own that will create your `Configuration` object, process all your class files collecting and interpreting your `@TableSpec` annotations and invoke `Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript()` or `generateSchemaUpdateScript()` to generate actual DDL.

As I said, rather involved :-) As an alternative, if ALL your mapped tables use the same tablespace, you can extend Oracle dialect you're using and override `getTableTypeString()` to return your tablespace spec. While this is an ugly hack (because tableTypeString's original purpose is to provide MySQL engine type), it works and is certainly a lot faster and easier than above approach.