# How to set tablespace for @Entity?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using `hibernate` to auto-create some postgres database tables.
Now I'd like to move one of the tables to a different location (harddrive).

This is done using `tablespaces`.

Question: how can I define the tablespace for an `@Entity`? Is that possible at all?

Comment: Check out [Hibernate Oracle Tablespace Annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274408/hibernate-oracle-tablespace-annotation).

Comment: @membersound have a look at [this](http://www.ciiycode.com/0HSS6eWgeqgg/hibernate-oracle-tablespace-annotation)

Comment: That's really lots of work to create an own `hbm2ddl` tool for this requirement...

Answer (score 1):

As of `4.3.9` version, there's no support for `tablespaces` in Hibernate, which leaves you with two options:

1. You either customize the `hbmddl` generation to include the `tablespace` as [previously suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274408/hibernate-oracle-tablespace-annotation).
2. You let go hbmddl and simply use your own [incremental database schema](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-integration-testing-strategies/) generation. [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/) is both simple and powerful, and you can get the most control over the database schema generation.

Comment: I agree, Hibernate should not manage the DDL stuff (although I prefer Liquibase over Flyway)